# Mac address re-authentication for captive portal

Tags: php, security, mac-address

I'm building a captive portal (PHP) where users can login with their social media account. After login, the wifi AP will grant the user access to the wifi network. So far so good.

I would like to reconnect the user when he visits a next time. Of course I would do this with a cookie. But unfortunately most devices do not support cookies on the pop up splash page.

Now I'm thinking about storing the mac addresses in the database with the user id. So the next time a device wants to connect with a known MAC address the user will be granted access automatically under the corresponding user id.

Let me be clear, there is no user data to be accessed in this login access, so no real harm could be don (theft of personal data is not possible). But as a developer I'm always looking into security issues. I know it is possible to spoof a MAC address. So what I really want is to store a second unique device variable with the MAC address that I can cross-reference so it would be more safer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: MAC addresses are only visible on the local network, not across the Internet.

Comment: Some devices don't even have a MAC address. There's no MAC address when using a dialup connection.

Comment: As far as I know, webservers don't send the client's MAC address to PHP.

Comment: And vice-versa @Barmar ! The client don't send the mac address to the server as it would be a major security flaw!

Comment: I understand your concern about the Mac address not send to PHP. But I do receive the MAC address from the AP the user tries to connect with.